# How to go via proxy while connecting to ADLS Gen2 through Hadoop/Java?

Tags: java, azure, hadoop, azure-data-lake-gen2

Below is a working program that connects to ADLS Gen2 through Hadoop and Java. Does anybody know how to set proxy details (host, port, username, password etc.) in **conf**?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

public class App {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
      // Set the configuration for the Hadoop client
      Configuration conf = new Configuration();
      conf.set("fs.azure.account.auth.type", "OAuth");
      conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider");
      conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint", "<endpoint>");
      conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id", "<client_id>");
      conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret", "<client_secret>");

      // Connect to ADLS Gen2 using the Hadoop client
      FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new URI("<abfs_uri>"), conf);
      Path filePath = new Path("/data.avro");
      FSDataInputStream inStream = fs.open(filePath);

      // Read data from the file in ADLS Gen2
      byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
      int bytesRead = inStream.read(buffer);
      while (bytesRead > 0) {
         System.out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
         bytesRead = inStream.read(buffer);
      }

      // Close the input stream and the file system
      inStream.close();
      fs.close();
   }
}
```

I've tried setting the properties like below but they don't seem to get honoured:
`conf.set("fs.azure.proxy.host", "<httpsProxyHost>");`

Answer (score 0):

It just uses the java sysprops mechanism, as covered in [the oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html)

There are some cloudera docs [which cover how to pass these through distcp and similar apps](https://docs.cloudera.com/cdp-private-cloud-base/7.1.6/cloud-data-access/topics/cr-cda-distcp-and-proxy-settings.html)...it is a bit trickier than for hadoop properties and if wrong you get a job which launches fine but then fails in its workers.